# How to import customize Style.xaml in universal windows library into a UWP application?

Tags: xaml, dll, uwp

I have "Generic.xaml" in my personal universal windows library, I import the .dll file to my UWP application project, but I don't know how to set this resource dictionary to my UWP application.
This is the context of my library project:[context of library project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE1FV.png).

I tried this in App.xaml in my UWP application:

```
<Application
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="xxx.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="using:Dart.Toolkit.UWP.Controls"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And apparently it's wrong, but I don't know what can I do. I know that I can copy this resource dictionary to App.xaml every time I create a new UWP project, but it's too hard to maintain.

Comment: Please try to use   `<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Dart.Toolkit.UWP.Controls/xxxx.xaml"/>`

Answer (score 0):

> How to import customize Style.xaml in universal windows library into a UWP application?

Please check [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#merged-resource-dictionaries) here. If you have place style.xaml in your `Dart.Toolkit.UWP.Controls` library, you could use `ms-appx:///` uri scheme to load it.

For example

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Dart.Toolkit.UWP.Controls/Style.xaml"/>
```

And please make sure the xaml file path is correct.